# Did old propeller aircraft begin takeoff off-center to counter p-factor?

Tags: aviation-history, p-factor

I have tried to ask this [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23628550#23628550) and I have been invited to ask a full fledged question here.

Is it true that an old (say about between the two world wars) take-off technique, to compensate for the p-factor experienced at high throttle settings, was to put the aircraft misaligned to the runway and let the p-factor align the aircraft to the center-line?

Example: take an aircraft with a p-factor that makes it yaw to the left, the pilot would have placed the aircraft on the left side of the center-line, with the nose to the right (so, looking at the center-line).

Comment: Never heard of that method, but in his Taildragger Tactics book, Sparky Imerson describes how to land on a slight diagonal down the runway to help reduce crosswind component, so there's no telling how creative pilots can get when they have to.

Comment: An off-center takeoff gives the pilot a better view of the runway. Airplanes back then were almost all taildraggers, and forward visibility on the ground was poor.

Answer (score 2):

Why ask in past tense? The [Mü-23 motor glider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaflieg_M%C3%BCnchen_M%C3%BC23_Saurier) has a central wheel and would need someone to hold a wingtip during take-off. Sometimes, a different technique is used: The aircraft is parked at a right angle to the (grass) runway, with the wingtip pointing into the intended take-off direction on the ground. When the pilot opens the throttle, he steps on the rudder, causing the aircraft to swerve into the desired direction and rotating into a horizontal attitude thanks to the centrifugal force.

[image: Akaflieg München Mü-23]

Akaflieg München Mü-23 (picture [source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Akaflieg_Mue_23.jpg))

Comment: Why I ask in past tense? From the wiki page: `Number built 1` not exactly common to come across, is it? :P

Comment: @Federico: Unless you are flying from the [Königsdorf airfield](http://www.dulv.de/Flugplatz/details.php?id=1340).

Comment: Also, this aircraft seems to be doing it because of the single wheel, not to compensate for the p-factor. Are there examples of aircrafts/pilots doing it for p-factor related necessity?

Comment: @Federico: I admit, this is not answering your question. But p-factor is also at work when uprighting the Mü-23.

Comment: Peter, as you mention, this does not answer the question, but it is upvoted, meaning that the system behind SE thinks that my question is answered. Could you help me having a chance of receiving an answer?